# Difficult Integral Involving the $\ln$ function

Tags: integration, logarithms, indefinite-integrals

Please help me solve this integral!
I have tried multiple different procedures for integration by parts, as well as substitution and have not come up with anything.
$$\int\frac{\ln x}{(\ln x+1)^2}dx$$

Thank you

Comment: Can you give us an idea of where you got stuck in your attempts?

Comment: Everywhere haha. I mean i didn't know how to properly split up the integral into the two parts

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Setting $\ln x=y\implies x=e^y$

$$\int\frac{\ln x}{(\ln x+1)^2}dx=\int\frac y{(y+1)^2}e^y dy$$

$$=\int\left(\frac{y+1-1}{(y+1)^2}\right) e^ydy=\int e^y\left(\frac1{y+1}-\frac1{(y+1)^2}\right)$$

If $\displaystyle f(y)=\frac1{y+1}, f'(y)=?$

Now,
$$\int e^y\left[f(y)+f'(y)\right]dy=f(y)e^ydy+f'(y)e^y=d(e^yf(y))$$

Comment: Thank you very much! So is there any particular recipe or method to solving these types of questions? What are the things that are important to recognize?

Comment: @user130996, the replacement of $ln x$ can be a good point to start. Then, taking out $e^y$ as common factor

Comment: that was some tite methodology dude

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
\begin{align}
&\mbox{Note that}\quad\int{\ln\pars{x} \over \bracks{\ln\pars{x} + 1}^{2}}\,\dd x
=\left.-\,\partiald{}{\mu}\int{\dd x \over \mu\ln\pars{x} + 1}
\right\vert_{\mu\ =\ 1}
\end{align}

> \begin{align}
> &\int{\dd x \over \mu\ln\pars{x} + 1}={1 \over \mu}
> \int{\dd x \over \ln\pars{x} + 1/\mu}
> ={\expo{-1/\mu} \over \mu}\
> \overbrace{\int{\expo{1/\mu}\dd x \over \ln\pars{x\expo{1/\mu}}}}
> ^{\ds{\mbox{Set}\ t\equiv\expo{1/\mu}x}}\ =\ 
> {\expo{-1/\mu} \over \mu}\int{\dd t \over\ln\pars{t}}
> \\[3mm]&={\expo{-1/\mu} \over \mu}\bracks{{\rm li}\pars{t}
> +\pars{~\mbox{a constant}~}}
> ={\expo{-1/\mu} \over \mu}\bracks{{\rm li}\pars{\expo{1/\mu}x}
> +\pars{~\mbox{a constant}~}}
> \end{align}

$\ds{{\rm li}\pars{x}}$ is the
[Logarithmic Integral Function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_integral_function).

> \begin{align}
> &\color{#66f}{\large\int{\ln\pars{x} \over \bracks{\ln\pars{x} + 1}^{2}}\,\dd x}
> =\left.-\,\partiald{}{\mu}\braces{
> {\expo{-1/\mu} \over \mu}\bracks{{\rm li}\pars{\expo{1/\mu}x}
> +\pars{~\mbox{a constant}~}}}\right\vert_{\mu\ =\ 1}
> \\[3mm]&=\color{#66f}{\large{x \over \ln\pars{x} + 1}} + \pars{~\mbox{a constant}~}
> \end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Integration by parts can be made to work

$$\int \frac{\log x}{(1 + \log x)^2} = \int x \log x \frac{1}{x(1+ \log x)^2} = \int x\log x \left(\frac{-1}{\log x + 1}\right)'  =$$

$$\frac{-x\log x}{\log x + 1} + \int (x \log x)' \frac{1}{\log x + 1} = \frac{-x\log x}{\log x + 1} + \int (1 + \log x) \frac{1}{\log x + 1} = $$
$$\frac{-x\log x}{\log x + 1} + x + C = \frac{x}{\log x + 1} + C$$