# Need help integrating $\int e^x(\frac{x+2}{x+4})^2 dx $

Tags: calculus, integration

I have simplified the problem a bit using integration by parts, with $u = e^x(x+2)^2$ and $v = 1/(x+4)^2$ but I'm then stuck with how to integrate this:

$$\int\frac{e^x(x^2+4x+8)}{x+4}dx. $$

I've considered substituting $t = e^x$, but this doesn't seem to make the problem any easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since 
\begin{align*}
\left(\frac{x+2}{x+4}\right)^2 &= \frac{x^2+4x+4}{(x+4)^2} \\
&= \frac{4}{(x+4)^2}+\frac{x(x+4)}{(x+4)^2} \\
&= \frac{4}{(x+4)^2}+\frac{x}{x+4} \\
&=f'(x)+f(x), \\ 
\end{align*}
let 
$$
\color{blue}{f(x)=\frac{x}{x+4}}.
$$

Now for $C$ constant, since 
$$
\dfrac{d}{dx}(e^x f(x)+C) = (e^x f(x)+C)' = e^x f'(x)+e^x f(x), 
$$
we have 
$$
\int \left(e^x f'(x)+e^x f(x)\right)dx = e^x f(x)+C. 
$$
So for the above indefinite integral, 
$$
\begin{align*}
\color{green}{\int e^x\left(\frac{x+2}{x+4}\right)^2 dx} 
&= \int e^x \left(f'(x) + f(x)\right) dx  \\ 
&= \int \left(e^x f'(x)+e^x f(x)\right) dx \\
&= e^x f(x)+C \\ 
&= \color{green}{\frac{x\: e^x}{x+4} + C}.
\end{align*}
$$

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

$$(x+2)^2=(x+4-2)^2=(x+4)^2-4(x+4)+4$$

$$\int e^x[f'(x)+f(x)]dx=e^xf(x)+K$$

Can you recognize $f(x)$ here?

Comment: Thanks. Can you also help with the second integral?

Comment: @100110, You don't need to  integrate by parts. Start as hinted

Comment: Yes, but I'd like to know how one deals with an integral like that. Thank you.

Comment: @100110, Somehow we need to reach at the form $$e^x[f(x)+f'(x)]+$$ terms  whose integration is simple enough   See also : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/687468/difficult-integral-involving-the-ln-function/687472#687472   https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/714204/how-can-i-integrate-frac-ln-x-1-ln-x2/714209#714209   https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1725611/how-to-solve-int-frace-2x-sin2x1-sin2xdx

Comment: @100110 if you were given that second form of the integral you gave us and wanted to integrate it, it might just be easier to go backwards in integration by parts to get to your original form and then using this (or others) hint. To go backwards, think about applying integration by parts the same way, but switching your $u$ and $dv$ a little bit

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align*}\int e^x\left(\frac{x+2}{x+4}\right)^2\,\mathrm dx&=\int\frac1{(x+4)^2}e^x(x+2)^2\,\mathrm dx\\&=-\frac{e^x(x+2)^2}{x+4}+\int e^x(x+2)\,\mathrm dx\\&=-\frac{e^x(x+2)^2}{x+4}+e^x(x+2)-\int e^x\,\mathrm dx\\&=-\frac{e^x(x+2)^2}{x+4}+e^x(x+1)\\&=\frac{xe^x}{x+4}.\end{align*}